# Postgres: Query Values in nested jsonb-structure with unknown keys

Tags: postgresql

I am quite new in working with *psql*.
Goal is to get values from a nested **jsonb**-structure where the last key has so many different characteristics it is not possible to query them explicitely.

The **jsonb**-structure in any row is as follows:

```
TABLE_Products    
{'products':[{'product1':['TYPE'], 'product2':['TYPE2','TYPE3'], 'productN':['TYPE_N']}]}
```

I want to get the *values* (*TYPE1*, etc.) assigned to each *product*-key (*product1*, etc.). The product-keys are the unknown, because of too many different names.

My work so far achieves to pull out a tuple for each key:value-pair on the last level. To illustrate this here you can see my code and the results from the previously described structure.

**My Code:**

```
select url, jsonb_each(pro)
from (
select id , jsonb_array_elements(data #> '{products}') as pro
from TABLE_Products
where data is not null
) z
```

**My result:**

```
("product2","[""TYPE2""]")
("product2","[""TYPE3""]")
```

**My questions:**

1. Is there a way to split this tuple on two columns?
2. Or how can I query the values kind of 'unsupervised', so without knowing the exact names of '*product1 ... n*'

Comment: Just use `jsonb_each(elements).*`. Or a lateral subquery from which you then select.

Comment: If i do this I get an syntax error... Can you be bit more precisely, please? :) You need to see my edited query?

Comment: Ah, needs another grouping parenthesis… I meant [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=75344601702f7b06c01e757eb2dd35d7)